# Untar after uploading to linux from windows

Tags: linux, tar, filezilla, binary-files

I have created `tar.gz` from my linux server, and I downloaded the same to my linux system and   I successfully doen `untar` with `tar -xvf package.tar.gz`.

And now my issue

I downloaded same `package.tar.gz` to the windows system then uploaded to another linux server, and tried same command `tar -xvf package.tar.gz`. but it getting

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

as response. I also tried filezill manual trnasfer with `binary` mode.

How can I do the same ?

**Update**

When I directly download to the linux system its working fine.

When I downloaded to the windows system and try to extract with 7zip or winrar error is getting

When I download to windows and upload to linux same error getting

Comment: Some tar versions (or even just builds) need the z flag explicitly. Did you try tar -xzvf package.tar.gz ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too :(

Comment: It's possible the file got corrupted somewhere along the way. You could test that using md5sum on the linux boxes. On windows use http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/ to check. the md5sum of the file should be the same in all locations. if it isn't there is a problem with the file.

Comment: are both linux boxes with the same os version/same version of tar? maybe one is gnutar and the other is bsdtar. what do you get from 'which -a tar' and what from 'tar --version' on borh linux machines?

Comment: @konqui yeah, If I directly download to the that linux system it will work :(

Comment: Just a passing thought. How did you do your downloads and copies? If you used FTP or a CMD copy command, and the file appeared to be ASCII, LF (0x0A) would be mapped to CR-LF (0D-0A) during the copy. If so, make sure you force binary mode (FTP type binary, CMD copy /b). With a hex viewer have a look for 0A in the archive and make sure there is no 0D with each occurrence.

Comment: I downloaded using browser, and uploaded with binary mode

Comment: Try opening it with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). It is a really nice program for opening and creating lots of different formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can break it down to unzip first then untar

```
gunzip package.tar.gz
tar xfv package.tar
```

or do it in one command

```
gunzip -c package.tar.gz | tar xfv -
```

It maybe on the other Linux system the tar does not recogize gz files or needs the z flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can gunzip and untar in one step without using pipe:

```
tar xvfz package.tar.gz

or depending on the tar version you have, you may need a dash -

tar -xvfz package.tar.gz
```

which is equivalent to

```
gunzip -c package.tar.gz | tar xfv -
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 rep yet so I cannot add comments, only reply.

Do what Jason Lewis mentioned.  Get the md5 hash of the files and see if they get corrupted along the way somewhere.

On linux, use md5sum command

On windows, download Microsoft's FCIV tool and use that.

Then you can see if the file gets corrupted while transferring to windows, or if it is pristine to windows but then getting corrupted while then transferring to linux.  This will narrow your debugging A LOT

FCIV is here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Windows example fciv

http://geekswing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/windows_md5sum_sha1_example.jpg

Comment: On Windows 10, you can use `CertUtil -hashfile <file> MD5` which is available. It gives the same MD5 checksum as FCIV.